# Summarize data from fileInput to use in updateCurrencyInput / updateNumericInput

Tags: r, dplyr, shiny, shinydashboard

Currently creating a sales report generating site in `R` using `Shiny`. I have been struggling to pull the data from a CSV file the user imports into the dashboard itself. I need to use the data from my `fileInput` to run a calculation and then actively display these results in my shiny window. Ideally this would be initiated by the action of selecting the CSV file for the `fileInput` by the user and the calculations would occur.

Let's say this is the CSV that the user inputs

| ID | DATE | GROSS |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 000001 | 5/22/22 | 75000 |
| 000002 | 5/25/22 | 100000 |

Here is an abridged version of the related code

```
# Load packages
library(shiny)
library(bslib)
library(shinyWidgets)
library(dplyr)

# Define static variables
mayquota <- 135000

# UI
ui <- navbarPage(title = "Example", 
                 tabPanel(title = "Page 1", 
                          fluidPage(inputPanel(textInput("key", "KEY")),
                                    fixedRow(column(12, fileInput("salesdata", "SALES DATA", 
                                                    width = 100%, buttonLabel = "SELECT"))),
                                    inputPanel(currencyInput("profits", "PROFITS", format = "dollar", 
                                                             value = 0, align = "right"),
                                               currencyInput("quota", "QUOTA", format = "dollar",
                                                             value = 0, align = "right"),
                                               currencyInput("difference", "DIFFERENCE", 
                                                             format = "dollar", value = 0, 
                                                             align = "right")))))

# Server
server <- function(input, output, session) {
  prof <- reactive({read_csv(input$profits)})
  toListen <- reactive({input$key})
  observeEvent(toListen(), 
               {if(input$key == "test123") 
                {updateCurrencyInput(session, "quota", value = mayquota)
                 updateCurrencyInput(session, "difference", value = profits() - mayquota}})
}

# Run application
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

[image: Test App Interface]
I need to pull the sum of the *GROSS* column in the CSV and use it to `updateCurrencyInput` in the form of:

```
updateCurrencyInput(session, "profits", value = profits())
```

I was hoping that something like this would work:

```
toListenFile() <- reactive({input$salesdata})
observeEvent(toListenFile(), {profits <- reactive({prof() %>% summarize(sum(`GROSS`))})})
```

But I was given the error that `summarize` from `dplyr` could not be used on reactive data. So that is where I stand. Any help would be appreciated to achieve a similar function to `dplyr` in a reactive environment where the CSV data is inputted by the user.

Answer (score 0):

It appears as though I have a solution to my issue, just wanted to share since I already opened the question.

```
server <- function(input, output, session) {
  abcInput <- reactive({
    req(input$salesdata)
    tibble(read_csv(input$salesdata$datapath))
  })
  sumprof <- reactive({sum(abcInput()$`GROSS`)})
  observeEvent(input$rdata, {updateCurrencyInput(session, "profits", value = sumprof())
  })
```

There might be a more elegant way to achieve this, but this appears to work thus far.